# How to pull info off the bios as a file

Tags: windows, operating-system, ethernet, bios, info

I am messing around with some coding and have some used/broken computers. I would like to see what kind of stuff I can do remotely to these computers.

I have a PXE boot setup to install operating systems remotely. What I am wondering is that if there is a way to pull the system/hardware information off of the machines from another computer (ethernet preferably) at the bios.

From there, I would like to save it as a file externally?(I would also be curious if I could wipe the data on these remotely too).

Hopefully, this is clear enough, let me know if you have questions.

I will eventually figure this out but I was hoping for a kickstart in the right direction.

Thanks for the help in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe you can start 'hacking' the grub legacy source code, grub 0.97 already have network boot support, some file systems and a primitive hard disk driver.

As a bonuses, grub legacy works on protected mode but have some pretty simple functions to switch to real mode and from there you can call whatever BIOS services you want, so I think you can deviate grub from your primary function and adapt to your necessity.